# Using Data attributes With Data from an array

Tags: php, css, custom-data-attribute

I am using data-attributes in my portal page to describe favorite links.  This is very easy to do it you are using a regular list ( because you can individually put the custom "data-special" in.

However when you have lots of links in an array and you are using foreach

**how do you pick out and apply a data-special to individual links within the array?** ?  the way I see it its either all or none within the foreach.

data-special is my own declaration. I apply a Unicode character through CSS to the links that are special.

Thank you for reading and your time.

```
 $portal = array(

    "Twitter" => "http://twitter.com",
    //another 20 array elements       
);  
ksort($portal);

foreach ($portal as $key => $item): 
   echo("<li><a rel=\"external\" href=\"$item\">$key</a></li>");    
?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to add data-special to specific links but am unsure of how to pick them out as they are in an array

EDIT
This is what I am trying to achieve on perhaps 5 of some links in the array

```
<li data-special><a href="http://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor" rel="external">Kular</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you upload your code so we can get an idea of what you are talking about?

Comment: How do you determine if a link is *special*?

Comment: Maybe you should clearly state what is "I need to add data-sepcial to specific links..."? Or what you want to do with the special links?

Comment: You mean data-special is any array?

Comment: Some links in the array of links are used more than others. For instance twitter, how would I add data-special to just that link.  then using CSS it has a unicode character in front of it.  The output would be <li data-special><a href="twitter.com">twitter</a></li>.  But only for certain links

Comment: Again, **how do you determine if a link is *special*?** What designates 5 out of the 20 links as requiring the `data-special` attribute?

Comment: Simply by usage.  they would be considered a "favorite link"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any more, try something like this (filling in the blanks where required). I'm assuming you're using the UTF-8 content type

```
<?php foreach ($portal as $key => $item) :
$special = /* boolean statement; is $key or $item special */
    ? 'data-special="true"' : '';
?>
<li <?php echo $special ?>>
    <a rel="external"
       href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>">
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($key, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

A more concrete example might be if you wanted to set only the *Twitter* key to special..

```
$special = $key == 'Twitter'
    ? 'data-special="true"' : '';
```

Perhaps a better example might be...

```
// before the foreach loop
$specials = array('Twitter', 'Google', 'Facebook');
```

then, in your loop

```
$special = in_array($key, $specials)
    ? 'data-special="true"' : '';
```

Comment: You have the idea, perhaps 5 out of 20 array elements would want to have this <li data-special><link>name</a></li>

Comment: I edited my question to indicate what I am trying to acheive from certain links in the array

Comment: Phil I don't really know how I would designate a link in the array to be special or to insert the data-special because you cant add an attribute to the array.  I need the name and the link in the array to get what I want

Comment: @Brad My answer does exactly what you want (albeit I set a value for the `data-special` attribute, something you should *probably* do). You just need to figure out how you determine any particular item in the `$portal` array as requiring the attribute

Comment: Ah I see what you are doing, this makes sense. As noted before selection of a special link is simply a favorite link that is quickly recognizable in a group of links.  Thanks